# checking for a variable multiple times

Tags: python, if-statement, coding-style

I am writing some analysis scripts to in which there are a lot of conditions I need to satisfy to implement the code correctly. The code looks very messy because I have to keep checking for certain things. Here is a simplified version of my problem.

I have a variable name 'measurement_type'.

measurement_type can be 3 values, "transmission", "reflection", "both". I need to perform 2 different set of instructions depending on whether measurement_type is in ("transmission" or "reflection") or measurement_type == "both"

I going to simplify my problem here because I don't think that the actual code really matters.

If `measurement_type in ("transmission","reflection")` I only have to run this:

```
table = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
arr = []
for num in table:
    arr.append(num)
plt.plot(stuff)
```

Since I have to account for `measurement_type == 'both'`, I have to run this to check for that as well:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
arr1 = []
if measurement_type == 'both': 
    table2 =  pd.DataFrame(stuff) #always same dimensions as table1
    arr2 = []
for j in range(len(table)):
    arr1.append(table['data'][j])
    if measurement_type == 'both':
        arr2.append(table2['data'][j]
plt.plot(stuff)
if measurement_type == 'both':
    plt.plot(more stuff)
```

I am having to run the latter because I need to take care of the possibility of `measurement_type = 'both'`
This is getting out of hand because I am having to perform this check of whether or not "both" exists.

Is there a better way of doing this?
I would rather not have to type in `if measurement_type == 'both'` over and over again as my analysis scripts get longer and more complicated.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear.  According to your description, if you're in the second block of code, you already know that it's `both`; there is no need to check again, let alone twice more.

Comment: I still have to check for ```both``` because if it is not both and I do ```arr2.append``` it will give me a variable doesn't exists error. If I wasn't clear, sorry, but I meant to say that I am running the second block of code in place of the first one. This is because I want the same code to take care of all possible values of ```measurement_type```

Comment: To be running the second block in place of the first, you have already verified that it's `both`.  See your own comment at the head of that code: `If measurement_type == 'both' I am running this:`  If that is *not* the case, then we need you to give us an accurate sample of your logic.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I have changed it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have two essentially independent operations: one for all cases, and one for `both`.  Your original code is a bit difficult to follow, as you've seen:

```
if measurement_type == 'both': 
    table2 =  pd.DataFrame(stuff) #always same dimensions as table1
    arr2 = []
for j in range(len(table)):
    arr1.append(table['data'][j])
    if measurement_type == 'both':
        arr2.append(table2['data'][j]
```

Extract the parts independent of `both`; follow with a check and proper handling for your special case:

```
arr1 = list(table['data'])   # This should be a straight conversion; no need to loop.
if measurement_type == 'both':
    arr2 = list(table2['data'])  #Similar conversion
```

If your `table` type doesn't implement the `list` conversion, then at least use a comprehension rather than the loop:

```
arr1 = [c for c in table['data']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd just create a separate function which takes an argument `measurement_type` and separate the operations in two logical sections. Something like this:

```
def plot_data(measurement_type):
   table1 = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
   arr1 = []
   for j in range(len(table)):
       arr1.append(table['data'][j])
   plt.plot(stuff)
   
   if measurement_type == 'both':
       table2 =  pd.DataFrame(stuff) #always same dimensions as table1
       arr2 = []
       for j in range(len(table)):
           arr2.append(table2['data'][j]
       plt.plot(more stuff)
```

This might not be the most efficient (you might need to do the same loop twice) but if performance is not an issue it might be useful to break down your code into more logical sections.